# Why does OR 0 round numbers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I'm under the impression that the Number type in Javascript stores any number, integer or float, according to the IEEE floating point standard. If so, then why does bitwise OR-ing a number with 0 round it down?

Playing around with some other bit ops, it appears that when applying bit operations to floating point numbers, the number is first rounded towards 0 and then the bit operations are applied (with the numbers in Two's complement representation rather than IEEE). Is this correct?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, all bitwise operations will convert the input to a 32-bit *integer*.

Comment: @bfavaretto that's actually the first sentence on mdn for bitwise ops

Comment: @aaronman I've just seen that. But MDN doesn't explicitly say they become ints. The spec is clear about that, it always uses [ToInt32](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.5) on the input.

Comment: You can find the complete language spec online, @hchau.

Comment: @bfavaretto interesting I've never actually read through the spec or anything

Comment: @aaronman Once you start checking the spec to answer questions like this, you'll become addicted to it (...or mad)

Comment: @bfavaretto I usually answer c++ questions and I can tell you looking through the spec for that is never fun

Comment: @bfavaretto Thanks for the link to the spec. That cleared things up!

Comment: @hchau Glad to help. I added an answer based on the spec text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ECMAScript 5.1, all bitwise operations will convert the input to a 32-bit integer, and return a 32-bit integer. Regarding the operators `^`, `&` and `|`, [section 11.10](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.10) says:

> The production `A : A @ B`, where `@` is one of the bitwise operators in
>   the productions above, is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1) Let lref be the result of evaluating A.
>   2) Let lval be GetValue(lref).
>   3) Let rref be the result of evaluating B.
>   4) Let rval be GetValue(rref).
>   5) Let lnum be ToInt32(lval).
>   6) Let rnum be ToInt32(rval).
>   7) Return the
>   result of applying the bitwise operator @ to lnum and rnum. The result
>   is a signed 32 bit integer.

Note that [ToInt32](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.5) is applied on both sides before the operator is applied.

Answer (score 3):

Quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

> Bitwise operators treat their operands as a sequence of 32 bits (zeros and ones), rather than as decimal, hexadecimal, or octal numbers.

If you didn't treat the numbers like this the bitwise ops wouldn't make much sense, which is why it is done

Comment: More than that, the operands are converted to integers before applying the OR operation.

Answer (score 1):

At language level there is only floats, and temporary integers for bitwise operators.

[Per spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.5), a float is turned into a 32-bit integer by doing the *abstract* operation:

```
var n = (sign(number) * floor(abs(number))) % pow(2, 32);
if( n >= pow( 2, 31 ) ) {
     return n - pow( 2, 32 );
}
else {
     return n;
}
```

I must emphasize that this operation is abstract and certainly not done in the above fashion by any engine so don't draw any performance considerations from it. (This goes for any other spec operation too)